# Create Spring MVC application without internet access

Tags: java, spring, web, weblogic

I need to develop spring mvc application, and deploy it in server. But main concern is that deploying server doesn't have internet access. They need to access this application within their internal network only. Can we create spring MVC dynamic application which can run on that kind on server. How to develop that kind of application with using SPRING.

Final application should be deployed as war file in server.

I have tried something with using jar libraries, but in `servlet-context.xml` file it contains this kind of url which accessing internet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

How to deploy this kind of application with offline server. I am using weblogic server for deployment

Comment: spring jars already contain the schemas referred by the namespaces so this is not an issue

Comment: I have inserted the jar files in Lib folder but I got this error in deployment     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 9 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 115; <Line 9, Column 115>: XML-24500: (Error) Can not build schema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' located at 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd' at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.

Comment: *Line 9 in XM ...*  this is a different question and maybe your "real" one which you may want to consider to ask as a new question on SO. Please insert your full *servlet-context.xml* in the newly created question

Comment: That means, Isn't schemaLocation the problem?